# tabBar gets hidden when I navigate from one controller to another in tabbased application

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5

How to navigate any controller from tab based application? I have created one navigation viewController and I placed tabBarController into navigationController.

So my rootViewController is navigationController.

when I navigate from my home view screen to next viewController in tab based application, at that time it navigates successfully but tabBar gets hidden

Comment: how tabs you have in tabbarcontroller and in which tab, you try to push?

Comment: Aren't these *`Controller`s types? Shouldn't they be started with capital letters?

Comment: no i created custom tabbar Placed Four buttons

Comment: check my answer it works 100% @Vikram

Comment: are you using storyboard. sorry for previous answer i messed up with some other questions

Comment: ok no problem  I m not using storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Put navigation controllers as the Viewcontrollers of the TabBar. Push the necessary viewcontrollers (e.g Home, Others) into the navigation controllers. Now You can get the navigation inside the tab bar

Comment: sir I tried and it worked at first time........  when I tap on any tab I got               m                                   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray removeObjectsInRange:]: range {1, 2} extends beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Comment: Thank u som much for ur support... It really means a lot to me  Thank u   thnk u thnk u

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, It shows correctly. Initially your navigation controller has `tab bar controller on top` of navigation queue, when you try to push another view controller from your nav. It will `show another view controller`(it will push to top of queue) thats why, it hide your tab bar.(Assume if you push one VC to another VC, navigation controller `never show first VC's part`)

**My suggestion:** Your tab bar controller should be root view controller and you have to place navigation controller as child of tab bar controller. Then push your VC from it. It will show your tabbaritems.

You can try this(According to your's edition)

```
LocationsVC * vc = [LocationsVC viewController];    
 UINavigationController * nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:vc];
tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:homeVC, nav,servicesVC,forumVC, nil];
self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController ;
```

Then push your secondVC from LocationVC.m in any method as ,

```
-(void)pushToNextScreen
{
    SecondVC *secondVc = //creation;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVc animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you architect the view hierarchy appeared to be not right.

Please check it.

It should be as

```
 tabbarController 
        -> navigationController 
                   -> viewController
```

Comment: please give me example   I m not getting this structure

Comment: Well, you can make set your rootViewController as tabbarcontroller and navigation controller will be a child of tabbarcontroller, and other view controllers will be child of navigation controller.

Comment: Thnk u so much mani for ur response but actully It is working now but when I navigate from First view to another and then When I click on Home Tab then It is displaying SecondView constoller let me answer my code

Comment: Thank u so much for ur support... It really means a lot to me  Thank u   thnk u thnk u

Answer (score 0):

Use hirearchy like below,

```
TabbarController --> UINavigationController --> UiViewController

tabbarController.viewControllers = array of UINavigationController;
```

Then navigate from one controller to another controller using push method of selected tab (selected navigation controller)

Comment: sir I tried and it worked at first time........ when I tap on any tab I got m Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray removeObjectsInRange:]: range {1, 2} extends beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Comment: please give more details. App gives this exception when trying to remove object at index which is greater than array count.

Comment: I have four tabs when i click on first tab then it happens

Comment: Write below method and log tabbarController.viewcontrollers in it. - (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController.  Also check viewwillappear method of first tab controller. May be you are removing object from some array there.

Comment: FirstVC * v1 = [[FirstVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstVC" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController * nav1 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:v1];

 SecondVC * v2 = [[SecondVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondVC" bundle:nil];

Comment: UINavigationController * nav2 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:v2];

    ThirdVC * v3 = [[ThirdVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"ThirdVC" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController * nav3 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:v3];

Comment: have you found what was the problem ?

Comment: Thank u som much for ur support... It really means a lot to me  Thank u   thnk u thnk u